# Simple Hello World Issue in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm new to node.js and have this very simple code. I just want to say a Hi User every second to the users who have connected to the server.
Here's the code I have:

```
var http = require('http');

function newfunc(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type": "text/plain",
    "connection" : "keep-alive"
  });
  setInterval(function() {
    response.write('Hi User\n');
    response.end('');
  }, 1000);
}
http.createServer(newfunc).listen(7070);
```

I see the `Hi User` message only once, and seems as if `setInterval` is writing it only once. 
What am I doing wrong in this?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I stand corrected in the comments... Just remove the `response.end()` call and you should see something like what you were expecting.

**ORIGINAL RESPONSE:** What you are trying to do cannot be done in this fashion... The response to an HTTP request is only ever sent once: when `response.end()` is called (the first time). *Commenter points out that this is not really correct: what would be correct to say is that no further data can be sent in the response after `end()` is called.*

If you want to show an HTML page whose contents change every second based on server-side actions, you will need to use something like WebSockets (e.g. the Node-compatible http://socket.io/ library) and some client-side Javascript, which is somewhat more complicated than the code you have above. *In general, for non-trivial UI's that do more than just append to the response or do bi-directional communication, this type of approach is preferrable*

Comment: That's not at all true, the `response.write()` calls will actually flush data to the browser and the `response.end()` does a final flush and then kills the connection.  I'm not sure why modern browsers don't actually display these intermediate flushes, however.  I used to do this all the time, there may be specific headers that need to be sent